# Accessing WCF Services from javascript

Tags: javascript, json, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF service.In javascript,how to access this service.
One of the functions is follows. How to access this function in javascript,ajax.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Get_PersonelBilgi/Kul_Ad={kul_ad},Sifre={sifre}",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
Personel Get_PersonelBilgi(string kul_ad,string sifre);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can use a code like this, replacing with our data:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:YourPort/YourService/NameOfService.svc/Get_PersonelBilgi/Kul_Ad=0&Sifre=0",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```